# About getContext() in the Microsoft Teams JS SDK for Teams App

Tags: microsoft-graph-api, microsoft-graph-teams, microsoft-teams-js

We are developing a Teams app that needs to correct information of Teams meetings such as users' display name, object ID, Tenant ID, organizer's info as well as "anonymous user"'s display name. My questions are:

1, app.getContext() returns "undefined" in "displayName" though user's displayName is something. But it is getting "userPrincipalName". How do I get "displayName" as well?

2, How do I get "meetingID" to use [this API](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/api/onlinemeeting-get?view=graph-rest-1.0&tabs=http#request-1)?

3, How can I get anoymous user information either with Graph API or SDK?